# is an E-Commerce Website considered to be an external application that has to meet PCI compliance 6.3

Tags: pci-compliance

So it seems like PCI compliance has a number of factors that are either unclear or they contradict each other in the requirements.

We have an ecommerce website that we manage. I see a large number of items that are required in section 6.3 that apply to internal and external applications (including web admin panels to those applications).

Then there are only a couple requirements in 6.6 that apply to public-facing web applications.

Is an ecommerce site considered to be part of the "External applications" or are those things like CRM's and Accounting systems and a ecommerce website is considered to be a public facing web application?

If it is an external application then under 6.3 you are required to have manual inspection of all code but in 6.6 you don't have to have manual inspection of all developed code if you employ a web application firewall. This is the primary point of my confusion.

Comment: Or possibly a better way to ask this question is: Is the web developer required to complete an SAQ for managing and maintaining an ecommerce website for a client when hosted at a major service provider like Liquid Web? We do not store or record any CC numbers it is all transmitted across an SSL protected website.

Answer (score 0):

Any open source server-side dialect like Python can be utilized to make a shopping basket. For a fledgeling, PHP sentence structure is less complex to process.

You have to learn PHP to assemble something like a shopping basket content administration framework.

With front-end aptitudes, you could create custom topics for open source stages like Magento to supplement your wage until the point when you learn PHP.